# How to make 3D animation with Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, three.js

I have background on Canvas 2D context, but i want to perform a 3D animation like [this one](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/3d/), is Three.js library the best choice to do such animation? Can you point me to some useful tutorial or documentation that may help. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one of the most common choices.

As WebGL enables OpenGL without the need for libraries, you might also do it with just [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) but that would be harder as WebGL doens't offer much more refinement over the raw and crude OpenGL.

Apart three.js, you could also try [GLGE](http://www.glge.org/) or [PhiloGL](http://www.senchalabs.org/philogl/) but as [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) is the most popular I would recommend to go for it if you have no specific requirement.

Comment: Thanx for your clarifications, you point me to the right way ;)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the demo you linked to is using a canvas library called Clay.js. Not one that I've personally heard about until now. For 3d in canvas the most popular one I know of it Three.js as you already mentioned. It has the benefit of supporting webGL as well (browser based openGL variant).

Three.js has limited [documentation](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/50/) and [some](http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/) [examples](http://yomotsu.github.com/threejs-examples/) but outside of some books you may buy there isn't a lot of hand holding. You basically need to dive in and start coding. Here are some online resources that may help you get started (not necessarily all focused on THREE.js):

http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/

http://learningthreejs.com/

http://learningwebgl.com/blog/

To make it easier to work with THREE.js Jérôme Etienne created a project called [tQuery](http://jeromeetienne.github.com/tquery/) which you can think of kinda like jQuery. A wrapper to make it easier to get your hands dirty. Here's a [video](http://vimeo.com/43336826) where he shows how to create a webGL game in 10 minutes.

Comment: If I may humbly self-promote http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/ - a collection of introductory examples with detailed comments in the source code.

Comment: @LeeStemkoski haha you are the "some" in my "some examples" links. Thanks for putting together those examples though, very helpful!